# Why is window.kendo undefined in jsfiddle

Tags: kendo-ui, undefined, jsfiddle

H there,

I have created a JSFiddle.
I have linked up the following external resources:

```
http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/jquery.min.js
```

And I have the following markup:

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

And I have the following JavaScript:

```
alert($("#test").html());
alert(window.kendo.guid());
```

The first alert returns 'Test' as expected.
The second alert fails.

I have tested the kendo js external resources in the address bar of the browser and they both load.
Why is window.kendo undefined?

Regards,

Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it is the order of the external resources.  When I changed them to the following order, it worked fine:

```
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/jquery.min.js
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css
http://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js
```

Regards,

Scott

Comment: Correct! Kendo UI depends on jQuery and some code runs just after you load the JS. If you do not have jQuery already loaded it fails.